# Behavior of Commonest when there is an even split between the elements of the list it is given

Tags: probability-or-statistics

How can I alter `Commonest` so that, when I give it an input of four zeroes and ones such as $\{0,1,1,0\}$, which has an even split in its elements, it returns the first element of the input list, which happens to be $0$ in the example?

Comment: Why not just `First[Commonest[{0, 1, 1, 0}]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second argument of `Commonest`:

```
Commonest[{0, 1, 1, 0}, 1]
(* {0} *)
```

Docs on [Commonest>>Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Commonest.html):

> *Commonest[list,n]* returns the *n* commonest elements **in the order they appear in** *list*.

**Update:** As discovered by m_goldberg (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58739/125)) and fixed by Mr.Wizard (see [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58760/125), `Commonest` has a bug in Version 10. So, for Version 10, you need to modify `kernel.init` with Mr.Wizard's fix, or as suggested by @Rahul Narain in the comments, use

```
 First@Commonest[{0, 1, 1, 0}]
```

instead of `Commonest[{0, 1, 1, 0}, 1]`.

Comment: I get `{1}` from `Commonest[{1, 1, 0, 0}, 1]` on V10.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to kguler's answer.

There is, to me, an inexplicable change in behavior of `Commonest` between V9 and V10.

```
data = Permutations[{0, 0, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}
> ```

**V9**

```
Commonest[#, 1] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {1}, {1}}
> ```

**V10**

```
Commonest[#, 1] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{1}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
> ```

Therefore, in V10 the first element is never returned as a tie breaker.

Comment: In fact it seems that in version 10 it is always the *last* of the equally-common values that is returned.  `data = Permutations[Riffle[#, #] &@Range[5]];
Position[DeleteDuplicates@#, Commonest[#, 1][[1]]] & /@ data // Union` yields `{{{5}}}`.  I think that must be considered a bug.  Will you post a Question highlighting this so that we may tag it as such?