# A bug in Commonest in version 10

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

m_goldberg [demonstrated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58739/121) that in *Mathematica* 10 [`Commonest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Commonest.html) does not behave as the documentation indicates that it will.  Concisely:

[image]

```
Commonest[{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 1]  (* should return {1} *)
```

> ```
> {3}
> ```

The function did behave as it was supposed to in earlier versions.

Comment: Shall I tag this as a bug?  Per protocol I am waiting for confirmation.

Comment: Confirmed, the error exist in v 10.0.0.0 but not in v 9.0.1.0. This seems like a Bug to me.

Comment: I had written up a version of the this question off-line, but when I came to upload it, I found you had beat me to it.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm sorry; when you didn't reply to my earlier comment I figured you were either away or not interested.  If you want you can post the question anew and I can merge this one into that, which will move my existing answer over.  Would that be agreeable to you?

Comment: No, I don't think we need to do that. I think it will be fine to let your version of the question stand.

Comment: I reported this problem to WRI tech support and gave a link to this question. I have received a response agreeing that this is a bug.

Comment: Not fixed in 10.0.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Diagnosis

Spelunking the definition of `Commonest`, which is written in top-level *Mathematica* code, I see that the two parameter form is handled by this internal function:

```
Commonest; (* preload *)
? Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonestSetLength
```

> ```
> oCommonestSetLength[list_, n_] :=
>  Catch[Block[{res, reslen, ord}, res = Tally[list];
>    reslen = Length[res];
>    If[reslen < n, Message[Commonest::dstlms, n, reslen];
>     Throw[res[[All, 1]]]];
>    If[reslen == n, Throw[res[[All, 1]]]];
>    ord = Ordering[res[[All, 2]], -n, Less];
>    res[[Sort[ord], 1]]]]
> ```

(Contexts stripped from definition Symbols for clarity.)

### Bug fix

The problem lies with the use of [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html).  Consider:

```
 Ordering[{1, 5, 3, 4, 5}, -1, Less]
```

> ```
> {5}
> ```

This returns the position of the *second* appearance of the largest value, `5`, rather than the position of its *first* appearance as `Commonest` requires.

A one-line fix to handle the case of $n = 1$, suitable for inclusion in `kernel/init.m`:

```
Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonestSetLength[list_, 1] := Commonest[list][[{1}]]
```

### Optimization

I suppose the use of `Ordering` was a flawed attempt to optimize the earlier version's code which is correct but cumbersome:

```
res = Transpose[{res, Range[reslen]}];
res = Sort[res, #2[[1, 2]] <= #1[[1, 2]] &];
Sort[Take[res, n], #1[[2]] <= #2[[2]] &][[All, 1, 1]]]
```

This is quite slow due to the algorithm used by `Sort` when it is given a custom ordering function.  `Ordering` improves upon this but it broke the function for $n = 1$ in doing so.  Further the use of the custom ordering function (i.e. `Less`) *also* slows `Ordering`, though to a lesser degree.

Fortunately there is now a better tool for us to use: [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaximalBy.html).

```
commonest[list_, n_] :=
  Tally[list]\[Transpose] /. {a_, t_} :> 
    a[[ Sort @ MaximalBy[Range @ Length @ t, t[[#]] &, n] ]]
```

This is much faster than the System function:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
x = RandomInteger[1*^6, 1*^7];

Commonest[x, 99] // AccurateTiming
commonest[x, 99] // AccurateTiming

Commonest[x, 99] === commonest[x, 99]
```

> ```
> 3.688711
> 0.203512
>
> True
> ```

Sometimes the difference is less but I have not found a case where my function is not faster.
Therefore I recommend, in addition to the bug fix above, placing this code in your `kernel/init.m` file:

```
Commonest (* preload -- do not remove! *);

Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonestSetLength[list_, n_] :=
  With[{res = Tally @ list},
    With[{len = Length @ res},
      If[len <  n, Message[Commonest::dstlms, n, len]];
      If[len <= n, res[[All, 1]],
        res\[Transpose] /. {a_, t_} :>
          a[[ Sort @ MaximalBy[Range @ Length @ t, t[[#]] &, Min[len, n]] ]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

bug fixed in 10.0.2. WIndows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Commonest[{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 1]  (*should return {1}*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]